# Symfony YAML parsing content with comma

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Is there a bug within Symfony Yaml component or is this the intended behavior from the Yaml standard? As per my understanding the comma in the scenario below should act a regular content character.

```
\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse("test: 1,2");
```

Actual result:

```
array("test" => 12)
```

Expected result:

```
array("test" => "1,2")
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug within Symfony - or at least, it's Symfony expected behavior.  You passed a non-quoted value to the parser that looks like a number, so it treats it as such and strips out the non-numeric charcaters.  The Symfony documentation [talks about numeric literals](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#numeric-literals) in its [Yaml component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html), although that is in regards to underscores.  The [Symfony Yaml Format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html) documentation explicitly states:

> Finally, there are other cases when the strings must be quoted, no matter if you're using single or double quotes:
>
> - When the string looks like a number, such as integers (e.g. 2, 14, etc.), floats (e.g. 2.6, 14.9) and exponential numbers (e.g. 12e7, etc.) (otherwise, it would be treated as a numeric value);

If you run the following code you will get your expected result:

```
Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse('test: "1,2"');
```

Result:

```
["test" => "1,2"]
```

Notice how the double-quotes are indicating a string value that should not be treated as a numeric literal.

Comment: Yes. I ran the code both ways using Symfony's `Yaml::parse()` command directly.  I used the OP's code as well as the one I posted, and got the result that I posted.  I updated my answer to have text that is a little clearer.

Comment: in Symfony Yaml 2.8 ,you can trace the code to evaluateScalar method in Inline class, which is removing commas and type casting the string to float "(float) str_replace(',', '', $scalar);" because the first character is a number.